# How do I output text to a table cell that isn't an input text with different colors?

Tags: javascript, text

I'm doing a simple calc program in Javascript. I have everything working using these scripts as a role model:
http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/calculators/list_test.asp

I used the Wind Chill Calc as a model and example. The text result is placed in an HTML style input box. I want to display the text result in a table's cell, not an input text box. How is this done in Javascript?

The second part of this, is that I want to display the text result in two different colors. Red for negative number and green for zero and above.

Comment: show some code which you tried, so that we can try to solve your problem.

Comment: I would normally do that, but I didn't have a clue as to how to perform this function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**1st** problem - instead of this

```
form.windchill.value = chill;
```

Do this

```
document.getElementById("your_table_cell_id").innerHTML = chill;
```

**2nd** problem - add this to your JS

```
var clr = ( chill <= 0 ) ? "red" : "green";
document.getElementById("your_table_cell_id").style.color = clr;
```

Comment: Thanks, Zoltan. So the table cell id might be something like <TD id="total"> and then use document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = chill; ?
Do I need a library such as Jquery to use document.getElementById?

Comment: yes, the `id="total"` will do it ans you don't need jquery for `.getElementById` - it's vanilla JS

Comment: document.getElementById("total") is a pure javascript in-built method, hence no need of any library. :) if you want that to be implemented in jquery, it could be $("#total").